# Getting an error when executing a nested ScriptBlock from Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for method to create a wrapper around `Invoke-Command` that restores the current directory that I'm using on the remote machine before invoking my command.  Here's what I tried to do:

```
    function nice_invoke {
        param(
            [string]$Computer,
            [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock
        )
    
        Set-PSDebug -Trace 0

        $cwd = (Get-Location).Path
        write-host "cmd: $cwd"
    
        $wrapper = {
            $target = $using:cwd
            if (-not (Test-Path "$target")) {
                write-host "ERROR: Directory doesn't exist on remote"
                exit 1
            }
            else {
                Set-Location $target
            }
            $sb = $using:ScriptBlock
    
            $sb.Invoke() | out-host
       }
    
       # Execute Command on remote computer in Same Directory as Local Machine
       Invoke-Command -Computer pv3039 -ScriptBlock $wrapper    
    }
```

Command Line:

```
    PS> nice_invoke -Computer pv3039 -ScriptBlock {get-location |out-host; get-ChildItem | out-host }
```

Error Message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] 
does not contain a method named 'Invoke'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
+ PSComputerName        : pv3039
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the using shouldbe unecessary to prepare the second ScriptBlock. Did you investigate the datatype of $sb within the function? As you can see by the error `$sb` is only a string rather than a scripblock which is why it does not have a invoke option. In place it could be possible to just use `$ScriptBlock`.

Comment: @Seth unfortunately that is not the case, the `ScriptBlock` contents are internally a string-literal That is, variable expansion won't occur until the `ScriptBlock` is prepared for execution via `.Invoke()` or when using the call operator `&`. Either the `$using:` scope or providing an `-ArgumentList` is required here, but neither will preserve the original `ScriptBlock` type.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a `ScriptBlock` like this with the `$using:` scope, it will get rendered to a string-literal first. Use the `[ScriptBlock]::Create(string)` method instead within your `$wrapper` block to create a `ScriptBlock` from a `String`:

```
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($using:ScriptBlock)
$sb.Invoke() | Out-Host
```

Alternatively, you could also use `Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $ScriptBlock`, but you still have the same issue with the `ScriptBlock` getting rendered as a string. Nonetheless, here is an example for this case as well:

```
# Call `Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $ScriptBlock`
# $args[0] is the first argument passed into the `Invoke-Command` block
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($args[0])
$sb.Invoke() | Out-Host
```

> **Note:** While I kept the format here in the way you were attempting to run the `ScriptBlock` in your original code, the ***idiomatic*** way to run `ScriptBlocks` locally (from the perspective the nested `ScriptBlock` it is a local execution on the remote machine) is to use the [Call Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-) like `& $sb` rather than using `$sb.Invoke()`.

With either approach, the nested `ScriptBlock` will execute for you from the nested block now. This limitation is similar to how some other types are incompatible with shipping across remote connections or will not survive serialization with `Export/Import-CliXml`; it is simply a limitation of the `ScriptBlock` type.

---

Worthy to note, this limitation persists whether using `Invoke-Command` or another cmdlet that initiates execution via a child PowerShell session such as `Start-Job`. So the solution will be the same either way.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That won't work because `$ScriptBlock` does not exist in the remote session. The `$using:` scope or `-ArgumentList $ScriptBlock` is required (the latter would require referencing `$args[0]` instead of `$ScriptBlock` in that case).

Comment: You're right, my bad sorry, I was having a really hard time understanding OP's code or even why is the function useful at all.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yeah a better approach would be to simply `cd $using:pwd` rather than create `$cwd` and do it that way. However, there is still value in understanding how to provide a nested `ScriptBlock` to a remote or parallel PowerShell session.

Comment: Nicely done, though I suggest at least mentioning that a more "natural" way to invoke script blocks is with `&` (or `.`). That script blocks deserialize as _strings_ is certainly surprising and has been reported in [GitHub issue #11698](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11698); unfortunately, the decision was made not to fix the problem, for security reasons I personally find unconvincing.

Answer (score -2):

```
function nice_invoke {
    param(
        [string]$Computer,
        [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock
    )
    Set-PSDebug -Trace 0    
    $cwd = (Get-Location).Path
    write-host "cmd: $cwd"  
    $wrapper = {
        $target = $using:cwd
        if (-not (Test-Path "$target")) {
            write-host "ERROR: Directory doesn't exist on remote"
            exit 1
        }
        else {
            Set-Location $using:cwd
        }       
        $sb = [scriptblock]::Create($using:ScriptBlock)     
        $sb.Invoke() 
    }   
    # Execute Command on remote computer in Same Directory as Local Machine
    Invoke-Command -Computer pv3039 -ScriptBlock $wrapper 
}
nice_invoke -Computer pv3039 -ScriptBlock {
      hostname
      get-location 
      #dir
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality on [so]. You may want to provide an explanation as to what changes you made to the code and why.