# Invoke-Command with timeout

Tags: powershell

Trying to create an invoke-command with a 10 second timeout incase one of my computers is in a zombie state and doesn't respond.  Here's what I have so far below. But, one problem i'm having is that it doesn't behave like the normal invoke-command by reporting the output to the terminal as the command runs...

```
PS> Invoke_command_responsive -Computer pv3039 -ScriptBlock {
  gci -recurse -Path C:\ | out-host
}
Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Cannot convert the "gci -recurse -Path C:\ |  
out-host" value of type "System.String" to type  
"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command],  
                              ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  
CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

Finished
```

Here's my code:

```
function invoke_command_responsive {
  $start_time  = Get-Date
  $start_dir   = better_resolve_path(".")
  $watchdog    = 60
        
  $j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    set-location $using:start_dir | out-null
    iargs = $using:args
    invoke-command @iargs | out-host
  }

  # Wait for Job to Complete or TIMEOUT!
  while ($true) {
    if ($j.HasMoreData) {
      Receive-Job $j
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
    }

    $current = Get-Date
    $time_span = $current - $start_time
    if ($time_span.TotalSeconds -gt $watchdog) {
      write-host "TIMEOUT!"
      Stop-Job $j
      break
    }

    if (
      -not $j.HasMoreData -and 
      $j.State -ne 'Running'
    ) {
      write-host "Finished"
      break
    }

  }#end while

  Remove-Job $j 
}

function better_resolve_path {
  param(
  [string]$path
)

  $pathfix = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($path)
  return $pathfix
}
```

It kind of looks like it can't take a ScriptBlock from "using:"

Comment: Hey, have you considered accepting some of the answers to your previous questions? If you expect people helping you with your future coding questions mind as well start accepting those answers which solved your problem as a gesture of appreciation.

Comment: That `$using:` applied to a variable containing a script block unexpectedly results in a _string_ value and therefore requires `[scriptblock]::Create()` to rebuild it as a script block has been covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742987/45375) to your previous question, which in essence is a duplicate. Incidentally, you should accept that answer.

Comment: Hear, hear, @SantiagoSquarzon. It is important to note that it goes beyond the personal: in addition to rewarding the efforts of an answerer, an accepted answer is an important signal to future readers to show _what solved the problem_.

Comment: Have you considered using `wait-job -Timeout $Watchdog` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell just has trouble passing a scriptblock using "using:" syntax.

```
PS> invoke_command_responsive -Machine pv3040 -Cmd "get-location"
```

```
function invoke_command_responsive {
  param(
    [string]$Machine,
    [string]$Cmd
  )
    
  $start_time  = Get-Date
  $start_dir   = better_resolve_path(".")
  $watchdog    = 8 #seconds
    
  [ScriptBlock]$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($opt_cmd)              

  $j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    set-location $using:start_dir | out-null
    [ScriptBlock]$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($using:cmd)              
    invoke-command -Computer $using:Machine -ScriptBlock:$sb | out-host
  }

  # Wait for Job to Complete or TIMEOUT!
  while ($true) {
    if ($j.HasMoreData) {
      Receive-Job $j
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    }
    $current = Get-Date
    $time_span = $current - $start_time
    if ($time_span.TotalSeconds -gt $watchdog) {
      write-host "TIMEOUT!"
      Stop-Job $j
      break
    }
    if (-not $j.HasMoreData -and $j.State -ne 'Running') {
      write-host "Finished"
      break
    }
  }
  Remove-Job $j 
}

function better_resolve_path {
  param(
    [string]$path
  )
  $pathfix = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($path)
  return $pathfix
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to type your `$Cmd` parameter as `[string]`, as it only complicates the invocation syntax if quoting is involved. Use `[scriptblock]`.

Comment: `Wait-Job $j -TimeOut $WatchDog | Remove-Job` will handle the timeout for you...